# Convert Linq Data query to object type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm getting the error

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[StockManagement.Models.Client]' to type
>   'StockManagement.Models.Client'."

```
public class Client
        {
            public int ClientID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string Mobile { get; set; }
            public string Telephone { get; set; }
            public string Fax { get; set; }
            public string Company { get; set; }
        }


private StockDataClassesDataContext dc;
 public Client GetClient(int clientID)
        {
            dc = new StockDataClassesDataContext(ConString.DBConnection);
            Client query = (Client)(from tbclient in dc.tblClients
                                  where tbclient.ClientID == clientID
                                  select new Client
                                  {
                                      Address = tbclient.Address,
                                      ClientID = tbclient.ClientID,
                                      Company = tbclient.Company,
                                      Fax = tbclient.Fax,
                                      Mobile = tbclient.Mobile,
                                      Name = tbclient.Name,
                                      Telephone = tbclient.Telephone
                                  });
            return query;
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your query returns an `IEnumerable<Client>`, you need either `FirstOrDefault`, `First`, `SingleOrDefault`.. look at MSDN for the one that best suits you.

```
Client query = (from tbclient in dc.tblClients
                                  where tbclient.ClientID == clientID
                                  select new Client
                                  {
                                      Address = tbclient.Address,
                                      ClientID = tbclient.ClientID,
                                      Company = tbclient.Company,
                                      Fax = tbclient.Fax,
                                      Mobile = tbclient.Mobile,
                                      Name = tbclient.Name,
                                      Telephone = tbclient.Telephone
                                  }).FirstOrDefault()
```